# How to change the default port number for Telnet in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, telnet

I need to enable Telnet in a port number other than 23. I  installed use telnet through following procedure.

```
systemctl enable telnet.socket
systemctl start telnet.socket
```

I tried [some procedure](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/10/15/centos-7-rhel-7-change-openssh-port-number-selinux-enabled/#comment-11621) to change the port number but it is not working out.

Can you please let me know if there is any other way to change the default port number for Telnet in CentOS 7?

Comment: Why would you follow a guide about changing the SSH port when trying to configure Telnet? What EXACTLY did you try already?

Comment: i tried    semanage port -a -t telnetd_port_t -p tcp 2323. But not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change systemd service unit definition file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/telnet.socket`. The section `[Socket]` has by default:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=23
```

To change port number to which `in.telnetd` will respond to (via systemd), change `23` to `2323`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I think you are the only one know the answer for this in  earth  :).. Because i couldn't find answer in google. searched a lot.